# What does thread-count mean for bar.arrive PTX barrier synchronization instruction?

Tags: cuda, ptx

It is mentioned [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-bar) in the PTX documentation that `bar.sync` and `bar.arrive` barrier synchronization instructions can be used as below:

```
bar.sync      a{, b};
bar.arrive    a, b;
```

Where

> Source operand a specifies a logical barrier resource as an immediate constant or register with value 0 through 15.  Operand b specifies the number of threads participating in the barrier.

It also shows an example where a producer-consumer model is established using these instructions:

```
// Producer code places produced value in shared memory.
st.shared [r0],r1; 
bar.arrive 0,64;
...

// Consumer code, reads value from shared memory 
bar.sync 0,64; 
ld.shared r1,[r0];
...
```

I do not quite get the purpose of operand `b` in `bar.arrive`. While such operand in `bar.sync` can be used to control the number of threads involved in the barrier and wait until the thread count is reached, its use for `bar.arrive` is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things happen when all threads have arrived at a barrier:

1. All waiting threads are allowed to proceed beyond the barrier.
2. The barrier is re-initialized so it is ready to be used again.

You are probably thinking only of 1., which can only happen at a `bar.sync` instruction. Therefore it it obvious a `bar.sync` needs to know the number of threads participating in the barrier. However, the barrier can also be released at a `bar.arrive` which therefore also needs to know the number of participating threads.

Having said that, it is undocumented what happens if participating warps or even threads disagree on the number of threads involved. This could be seen as an opportunity to a daring inquisitive mind to find possible new (and unsupported!) synchronization constructs through reverse-engineering.

Comment: Can you please provide an example where releasing a barrier at a `bar.arrive` would be useful?

Comment: Whenever you want to use the same barrier more than once in your code.

Comment: My point is a design with `bar.arrive` executed by some threads or warps and with no `bar.sync` seems functionally redundant. Therefore, the barrier restart can be signaled only by `bar.sync`. Unless the existence of multiple `bar.sync` executed by multiple warps for a barrier is possible. For instance, a `bar.arrive 0,128` by one warp, and then `bar.sync 0,64` by another warp and `bar.sync 0,128` by two other warps.

Comment: You are right that all threads executing `bar.arrive` with no `bar.sync` would be a no-op, so there needs to be at least one `bar.sync` somewhere, and the total number of threads could be taken from there. That would however require the barrier hardware to have a register to store the total number of threads in case the last warp arriving at the barrier executes a `bar.arrive`. I suspect that register just doesn't exist.