# CUDA: Is it possibile to synchronize threads based on threadIdx?

Tags: cuda

As the title says, I wonder whether it is possible to launch a sort of `__syncthreads()` function, where the barrier is not at block level but at sub-block level, so that I can sync all threads having a particular threadIdx.x?

For instance, if I define a kernel launch as <<<1, (32, 32)>>>, is it possible to define something like `__syncthreads(5)` so that it syncs all threads having threadIdx.x == 5?

Following the documentation, it seems that CUDA does not define such a function; however, I wonder whether there exists some trick that can achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no this is not possible in CUDA.  There are no provided methods to do this.

CUDA does provide `__syncwarp()` which allows synchronization of a warp (32 threads).

The CUDA [cooperative groups](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/) mechanism does allow for synchronization "only" of subgroups of threads.  But you do not have an arbitrary method to assign threads to groups.

At the PTX level, there is [more flexibility in the use of barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487382/what-does-thread-count-mean-for-bar-arrive-ptx-barrier-synchronization-instructi).  But you don't have the ability to assign an arbitrary set of threads to a barrier.  (Instead, for example, arriving threads may simply be "counted").

My suggestion would be to use one of the above methods.  For example, if you wanted to assign all threads with threadIdx.x == 5 in a (32,32) threadblock, that is 32 threads the same as a warp.  Reassign your thread assignment pattern so that those 32 threads belong to the same warp, and use `__syncwarp()`.

Comment: Or synchronize all 1024 threads ...